# How to change the file type in RAW file from text to mp3..?

Tags: java, android

In android studio , I messed up certain settings and when I copy mp3 file into raw folder it opened as text file with corrupted letters ? How to fix this problem?

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "it opened".

Comment: and also what are those "certain settings"?